# In Dart, when adding two doubles the sum is less than it is supposed to be

Tags: dart

I guess it's something basic I haven't got yet, but

```
0.009 + 0.001; // => 0.009999999999999998
```

Why?

Comment: Yep, sounds like it. However, I should note, I ran the code in both Dartium and standalone dart interpreter, so it's not just Javascript broken, Dart is broken too.

Comment: Don't let the mention of JS in the title fool you. The answers there apply unaltered to almost every other modern language, because almost other modern language uses IEEE 754 binary floating point.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, haven't read the question's answer. It's not broken, but the behavior is exactly like Javascript. Which, I guess, is a good thing for now.

Comment: I programmed for years before I understood why floating point numbers behave this way. It is something simple but it takes a lot of information to understand what is going on.

Comment: @snitko It has nothing to do with JavaScript. It has everything to do with *relative precision floating point*. You have 64-bits for a "double". You can only represent so many *discreet* values (and yet there are infinitely many real numbers in the same range). See [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: @snitko Also see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which is from a comment in the duplicate.